# how to pull user information from facebook sdk into my site's database using php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-login

I have enabled facebook login in my site using Facebook's java script sdk. Now i want to pull user's basic information from facebook, and store it in my site's MySQL database. I need this to be done via php as the alternative signup page is implemented in php. If any other better way is possible, please do mention.

edit:
i follow that i need to use response object, but where m i supposed to place the object request? and php "post" codes?
I am relatively new to php, where do the below code lines belong?

```
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

});

Will return an array of values:

{
  "id":"101540562372987329832845483",
  "email":"example@example.com",
  "first_name":"Bob",
  [ ... ]
}

edit 2:

FB.api does the api call & receives the response object, containing the user information, but do i have to use the exact "code1" below or can i use the other way as in "code2" that i am familiar with?

code1:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
  var fbname=response.name;
  var fbid=response.id;
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: page_for_storing_information,
 data: "name="+fbname+"&uid="+fbid,
     success: function(msg){ 
      }
     });
 console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
  });
   } else {
   console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
});
```

code 2:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['response.name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['response.email']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['response.id']);


$sql="INSERT INTO questbook (name, email, id)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$comment', )";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

Comment: you need both codes, of course. "page_for_storing_information" is actually the php script (code 2). you send the data to php via ajax, and you store it in the database via php.

Comment: make sure you understand what javascript and php are for. php runs on the server, you NEED it to store something in mysql databases (or any other server language, that is). javascript runs on the client (except for node.js). and make sure you understand how those work together.

Comment: so code1 just does the job a usual HTMl form does? and passes values to php script on server side so the php scrip can alter mysql? correct?

Comment: exactly, that´s how it works

Comment: btw, take a look at $.post, it´s a short form for $.ajax. or don´t use jquery at all, better learn javascript before using a framework like jquery.

Comment: in html added <button onclick="FB.logoout();">Log out</button>  in script added FB.logout(function(response) {
        // Person is now logged out
    });

Comment: doesnt quite do anything though, btw went through the whole fb documentation, they need some examples for new guys to have a better understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58238/discussion-between-n0062eclipse-and-luschn).

Comment: are you sure you wrote it correctly? FB.logoout(); < that is wrong

Comment: yes i rectified it no problem. now trying to get that into my database :) using the code lines above

Comment: instead of this to send data to php file ->> data: "name="+fbname+"&uid="+fbid, can i use -->serialize()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook recommends using the new PHP SDK 4 for the API. It needs PHP 5.4+, make sure you got that on your server. Here are some links to get you started, the Facebook docs are not very detailed about the new PHP SDK (yet):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

What you may want to use is the "JavaScript Login Helper".

Edit: I realize that you don´t even need to use the PHP SDK for this, as you even request the basic data via JavaScript. So all you need to do is to use AJAX to call your php file with the database storage code.

Example AJAX code:

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
};
//send with POST
ajaxRequest.open('POST','yourscript.php',true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); //like a form
ajaxRequest.send('name=xxxx&fbid=xxxxx');
```

Not sure if you know how to use MySQL, but you should google for "PDO" - the recommended way to use MySQL with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: saw whats PDO, did some more digging got two ways to work around to my needs. I don't just want to copy code into my site, but understand how it works out the way it does.

Comment: Hurray for your thinking: learning is not just copy-pasting :)

Answer (score 1):

go through this - `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0`
all is described here.